# Service in Angular Library acts differently than local service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-library

I have a service called TextService in my angular library. The code is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TextService {
  constructor() {}

  getText(): Observable<string> {
    return of('Text from service.');
  }
}
```

I noticed some oddities when subscribing to getText that I'll get into in a second.  Because of the oddities, I created a local service in my test angular application that I'm using to test the library. The code is near identical.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SampleService {
  constructor() {}

  getValue(): Observable<string> {
    return of('Text from service.');
  }
}
```

In my SampleComponent.ts, I subscribe to both in the ngOnInit():

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TextService } from 'myangular-library';
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';
import { SampleService } from '../services/sample.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss'],
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscriptions: SubscriptionLike[] = [];

  serviceText: string | null = null;
  sampleValue: string | null = null;

  constructor(
    private textService: TextService,
    private sampleService: SampleService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.textService.getText().subscribe((text: string) => {
        console.log('Getting text from text service. Text: ' + text);
        this.serviceText = text;
      })
    );

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.sampleService.getValue().subscribe((value: string) => {
        console.log('Getting value from sample service. Value: ' + value);
        this.sampleValue = value;
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription: SubscriptionLike) => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

The oddity that I spoke about earlier is that getText subscribe function gets called per character while getValue subscribe function gets called once.  So, the console output is:

```
Getting text from service. Text: T
Getting text from service. Text: e
Getting text from service. Text: x
Getting text from service. Text: t
Getting text from service. Text:  
Getting text from service. Text: f
Getting text from service. Text: r
Getting text from service. Text: o
Getting text from service. Text: m
Getting text from service. Text:  
Getting text from service. Text: s
Getting text from service. Text: e
Getting text from service. Text: r
Getting text from service. Text: v
Getting text from service. Text: i
Getting text from service. Text: c
Getting text from service. Text: e
Getting text from service. Text: .
Getting text from sample service. Value: Text from service.
```

Why is the TextService returning one character at a time?

Comment: It doesn’t look like the provided code would produce the result you’ve described. Are you able to reproduce in StackBlitz?  Perhaps this is simplified code that is too simplified to show the problem.

Comment: As BizzyBob mentioned, the output describe isn't possible IMO. But I've got 2 ideas where it could come from. 1) instead of an `of` operator, you're using a `from` operator and passing the string directly to it. Because it usually takes an array, if you pass a string it'll char after char. 2) Somewhere, you have a switchMap and in the inner part of the switchMap, you return a string instead of an observable. That'd produce that output. If that's the case, replace the switchMap by a map and you'll only get 1 string instead of char after char.

Comment: @maxime1992, thanks for your comment.  It sparked something in my brain.  I had originally made it `from` instead of `of`.  But, I had since switched it.  I think there must have been some caching or something going on.  I completely deleted the dist folder then rebuilt and re-linked and it is working as expected now. Thanks!